# HttpHandler Object- to Determine the JQuery Calling Source Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have HTTP Handler FaqsJson.ashx which is creating a JSON utilizing the StringBuilder.
In this Handler Object I am calling a StoredProceedure and Im passing a single Variable FactTypeID.  For now this FactTypeID is hard-coded.

From within this Handler Object I need help to be able to iterate through some other Object or Server Variable
in order to determine the Source Page which called the Object.
Also, I need to be able to call this HttpHandler from the JQuery Functions of several .aspx Pages:
Im not clear how to check from which JQuery Source Page this Handler Object was called.
I would appreciate any help as Im completely unfamiliar with HttpHandler Object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DaVincisApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for FaqsJson
/// </summary>
public class FaqsJson : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Int32 FactTypeID = 6;
        string query = "dav_getFactsByFactType " + FactTypeID;

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            StringBuilder strFaqs = new StringBuilder();
            int start = 0;
            strFaqs.Append("[");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (start == 0)
                    strFaqs.Append("{");
                else
                    strFaqs.Append(",{");

                strFaqs.Append(string.Format("\"Question\":\"{0}\",", reader[0].ToString()));
                strFaqs.Append(string.Format("\"Answer\":\"{0}\"", reader[1].ToString()));
                strFaqs.Append("}");
                start++;
            }
            strFaqs.Append("]");

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            context.Response.Write(strFaqs.ToString());
            context.Response.End();

            reader.Close();
            myCommand.Dispose();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exception = ex.Message;
            // Logg the exception here
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            myCommand.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is one of my Source Pages PaintFaqs.aspx which should pass a Parameter = 1 to the Handler
Another Source Page Glossary.aspx should pass a Parameter = 6.
I would then check that Parameter within the Handler Object to set FactTypeID

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="PaintFaqs.aspx.cs" Inherits="DaVincisApp1.PaintFaqs" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ToggleFAQ(title) {
        //$("#" + title).toggle("slow");

        Aobj = document.getElementById(title);
        DIVobj = document.getElementById(title + "-link-div");
        LINKobj = document.getElementById(title + "-link-a");

        current_state = Aobj.style.display;

        if (current_state != "inline") {
            Aobj.style.display = "inline";
            Aobj.style.visibility = "visible";
            DIVobj.className = "question-clicked";
            LINKobj.className = "questionLink-clicked";
        }
        else {
            Aobj.style.display = "none";
            Aobj.style.visibility = "hidden";
            DIVobj.className = "faqquestion";
            LINKobj.className = "questionLink";
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('FaqsJson.ashx', function (datas) {
            var str = "";
            var index = 1;
            $.each(datas, function () {
                str += "<div id=\"A" + index + "-link-div\" class=\"faqquestion\">" +
                            "<a id=\"A" + index + "-link-a\" href=\"javascript://\" class=\"questionLink\" onclick=\"ToggleFAQ('A" + index + "');\">" +
                            this['Question'] +
                            "</a>" +
                       "</div>";
                str += "<div id=\"A" + index + "\" style=\"display: none;\"> " +
                            "<div class=\"faqanswer\">" +
                                "<div class=\"answerbox\">" +
                                    this['Answer'] +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>";
                index++;
            });
            $("#mid-featureleft-client .controlbox").html(str);
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="top-feature-client">
    <div class="contentheader">
        <img alt="image1" src="images/Facts/FaqHeader2.png" style="height: 245px; width: 848px" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mid-feature-client">
    <div id="mid-featureleft-client">
        <div class="contentheader">
            <h1>
                General Painting Facts</h1>
            <img height="16px" width="552px" src="Images/Columns/hr_red1.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="controlbox">
            <br />
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your page specific `FactTypeId` using query string. For example,

```
$.getJSON('FaqsJson.ashx?factType=1', function(...
```

And at the handler side,

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   int FactTypeID;
   var factType = context.Request["factType"];
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(factType) && int.TryParse(factType, out FactTypeID))
   {
      // we got the fact type id
   }
   else
   {
      // error, no fact type id - return error JSON response
      // TODO
   }

   ...
```